# Yii Rest api url manager

Tags: api, url, yii

I am not able to find the logic behind the url manager. Can any body tell me about the given url calling in Rest pattern. I have too many get methods in my Controller with single parameter.

This is my Original url :  localhost/project/api/event/getevent/event_id/1

api is Module
event is Controller
getevent is Controller action name
event_id is parameter 1

I want to convert this to Rest pattern    localhst/project/api/event/1

//Updated code..

all are related to same Model..............

```
    //Search by Event id
    public function actionByEventId(){

        $model->byEventId();
    }


    //Retrieve user's events by User id
    public function actionByUserId()
    {  

       $model->userEvents();  
    }

   //Search for event by code
    public function actionByEventcode()
    {      

        $model->byEventCode(); 

    }
```

Comment: Can you pleas add how you want to call them? like `localhst/project/api/event/1` and `localhst/project/api/user/1`?

Comment: no, i want like this  localhst/project/api/event/eventid/1 and localhst/project/api/event/userid/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule:

```
'api/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'api/<controller>/by<action>'
```

And add the `$id` your actions:

```
public function actionByEventId($id) {

}
public function actionByUserId($id) {

}
```

Now if you call `localhst/project/api/event/eventid/1` Yii will call the `actionByEventId` in your `event`-Controller with `$id` as 1

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with your code. its working fine for single method. I have multiple actions with one parameter. here, i am getting problem. what ever coming from api, it takes as ID. so i cant able to call multiple actions. can you please guide me.

Comment: @Kishore please add a second example to your question, that i can see how your structure looks like

Comment: hi, updated the main post. added 3 functions with single GET perameter in same controller.. how can i call these apis..

Comment: Thanks for your response. when i call the above url, eventid & userdid are taking as actions. getting error like unable to resolve this..no action name i there.. like that. But those two are parameters...

Comment: @Kishore: you can't run 2 actions at the same time

Comment: No, i am not running 2 actions at a time. My requirement is if parameter as eventid, then call byeventid action. and if parameter as userid then need to call byuserid action.

Comment: @Kishore: did you really copy all my code? By me it's working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63862/discussion-between-dinistro-and-kishore).